# PHP Array Elements Overriden by Last Written Value?

Tags: php, arrays, overriding

Good day to all. I have been breaking my head over a little issue in PHP, here it is:

```
$result = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $result[] = $ref_vars;
}
```

The $ref_vars have the correct value, being the new array fetched every time and are passed to the $result array.
When I print_r on $result the array is filled with the same information over and over, for example, all the arrays inside $result will have the same name, id number, etc etc.

How is this happening?
All help appreciated and good luck to all.

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: The most important part, yes. I am using fetch from prepared statements to get the array and put it into another array that will contain them all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of `$stmt->fetch()` to some value.

```
while ($ref_vars = $stmt->fetch()){
    $result[] = $ref_vars;
}
```

Comment: stmt->fetch() doesn't return the value it just assigns it to the variables declared in bind_result...

Comment: So please update your code to have better understanding what is going on.

Comment: The rest of the code will not make you understand better, if you have used prepared statements you would know fetch doesn't return the value of the variables it just binds them to the variables passed in to bind result. The point is the $result array is filled with the same information over and over as if the fetch statement was not working, which it is.

Comment: Do you use PDOStatement::fetch?

Comment: No I am using the mysqli library, btw thanks for sticking around to help.